# Cleaning Console and Appcelerator Titanium automatically closed everytime

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

**Hi!**
[image]

When i click on the clean button on console. Appcelerator Titanium Studio closed automatically. It happen all the time. 
And when i select **10 line** code and press **command+x (cut)** then appcelerator studio closed.

What is the reason can you guy's please tell me?

Comment: please add your studio and java version

Comment: Hi miga! Appc. Studio version is 4.7.1 and java version is 1.8.0_131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are reported bugs that are going to be fixed on the next Appcelerator Studio version (5.1.0):

Appcelerator Studio crashes intermittently on clearing logs: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8902

Comment: Thanks for it. Its mean i have to update Appc. Studio version 4.7.1 to 5.1.0. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I reported the [Appcelerator Studio is crashing when deleting multiple lines of text](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5475) back in December.

I just heard yesterday this will be fixed in Studio Release 5.1.0.

Comment: Thanks man. I have to update Appc. Studio from 4.7.1 to 5.1.0.